# Ability to multiply two parameter packs in C++ 11 in dot product fashion via variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

```
template<class...A, class...B> void func(A...arg1,int sz1, int sz2, B...arg2)
{
std::cout << "sizeof parameter pack for A = " << sizeof...(arg1) << std::endl;
std::cout << "sizeof parameter pack for B = " << sizeof...(arg2) << std::endl;
}

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   func<int,int,int,int>(1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8);

}
```

My question is how can i peel the first parameter of each of these packs and multiply them and then sum them with recursive call to reduced parameter pack of both the packs.

Esentially I want to implement :  `SUM(A[i] * B[i])`

Comment: Are you actually restricted to C++11, or newer standards can be used as well?

Comment: Does this even build? And if it does, do you get correct sizes printed?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using something other than parameter packs? Especially if your types will not really change between elements. Like [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) or even a container like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/variadic_templates.htm please read this StoryTeller and HolyBlackCat because there is concept of trailing and non trailing parameter pack as per this article. and yes the code does compile :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do that without recursion.

```
template<class...A, class...B> int func(A...arg1, int sz1, int sz2, B...arg2)
{
    std::vector<int> p = {(arg1 * arg2)...};
    return std::accumulate(p.begin(), p.end(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling your function with `func<int,int,int,int>(1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8);`? I get (clang++ 3.9) an "error: no matching function for call to 'func'" with "note: candidate function not viable: requires 6 arguments, but 10 were provided"

Comment: yeah I ran it with your main function. Works without problems for me. http://cpp.sh/3ofqq

Comment: ACB is my man! i never knew from examples online that this way of argument pack multiplication is actually legal. :)

Comment: Or even `return ((arg1 * arg2) + ...);` in C++17.

Answer (score 0):

There is no needs of recursion (if you don't want a C++11 `constexpr` returning function).

Suggestion: instead of a couple of variadic arguments use a couple of C-style arrays as follows

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T func (T const (&a1)[N], T const (&a2)[N])
 {
   T ret {};

   for ( auto ui { 0u } ; ui < N ; ++ui )
      ret += a1[ui] * a2[ui];

   return ret;
 }
```

This way you have: (1) an homogeneous `T` type instead a couple of variadic type lists and (2) that the two list must be of the same size `N` or the function doesn't match. I suppose they are advantages if you want a `sum(a[i] * b[i])`

The function should be called with a couple of initialization list (that is: wrapping in brackets the two lists)

```
// print 70 
std::cout << func({1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}) << std::endl;
```

Different if you need a `constexpr` function: the `func()` can be `constexpr` starting from C++14 but not in C++11.

If you want a C++11 `constexpr` function you need it recursive but there no need of "peel the first parameter of each of these packs": you can use and index (with a default starting value of zero)

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T func (T const (&a1)[N], T const (&a2)[N], std::size_t pos = 0u)
 {
   return pos < N 
      ? a1[pos] * a2[pos] + func(a1, a2, pos+1u)
      : T{0};
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP says

> My whole aim is to do this using parameter packs only :)

I see...

Well, I suppose that, in C++11, you can use trick of the initialization of an unused array

```
template <typename ... As, typename ... Bs>
auto func (As ... args1 ,int, int, Bs ...args2)
    -> typename std::common_type<As..., Bs...>::type
 {
   using unused = int[];

   typename std::common_type<As..., Bs...>::type ret{};

   (void)unused { 0, ( ret += args1 * args2, 0 ) ... };

   return ret;
 }
```

If you can use C++17, you can write

```
template <typename ... As, typename ... Bs>
auto func (As ... args1 ,int, int, Bs ...args2)
 {
   return ( (args1 * args2) + ... );
 }
```

Comment: My whole aim is to do this using parameter packs only :) or else i have 100 other ways to do this including kdb/q functional programming where it is done like  p.q [ where p and q are arrays of same length ] :)

Comment: @AnandKulkarni - answer modified; off topic suggestion: when you write something to a person different from the author of the question or answer, precede the comment with `@<name of the person>` or she/he doesn't receive a notification.